# Can we use entity framework with wcf service?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

We are planning to upgrade our old services to WCF services. I am thinking to use entity framework as data layer for my service. Can I use it? Do I need to map my entities to data contracts in my service? Can't I use the entities as my data contracts? I worked with entity framework and WCF independently but never used them together. Please advice.

Comment: No, don't use entities as data contracts. That exposes implementation-specific fields, like the base fields that do change tracking. This applies to database-first, of course. If you use code-first, then it's your code, so it should be ok.

Comment: So, I can use EF as a DB layer, write my own data contracts and map my entities to Data contracts in my code. Nice. Also, can I generate dynamic connection string instead of having connections strings in my config file?

Comment: I've never done connection strings like that, but I don't see why not. I'm pretty sure there are overloads that accept a connection string, or at worst, a `SqlConnection`. You can also, BTW, use T4 Templates to _generate_ your Data Contracts if you're clever enough. That gives you a nice, maintainable way of keeping the DTOs up to date with the model.